# The root word of hospitability

Tags: morphology

I am taking morphology class this semester but I am confused with something. What is the root of the word hospitable? When I searched in internet I conclude that the root is the word host or at least hospitable. But then my lecturer said that it was come from the word hospice. I just could not understand what kind of word process and word formation involve if its true it is come from the word hospice. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The full (subscription-only) OED says ***hospitable*** derives from *obsolete French **hospitable** (Cotgrave 1611), or < Latin type **hospitābilis** , < **hospitāre** : see **hospitate** adj. and -**ble** suffix*. And for ***hospitate*** it says *(rare) **Devoted to the purposes of a hospice.*** So chalk one up to your lecturer!

Comment: @FumbleFingers what you mean, chalk one up to their lecturer. Nonono. In English, the root of *hospitable* is *hospitable*. As your own quote confirms.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Splitting hairs much? If OED says "see [other English word]" in their "etymology" section, I'm happy to understand that as meaning "the etymology the current word is the same as / related to that of [other English word]". There may indeed be "deeper" roots than that, but it seems reasonable to me to say that ***hospice*** is somewhere in the ancestral tree of ***hospitable*** (whether as a *direct* ancestor, or just some kind of "great aunt" isn't clear to me). But rare or not, ***hospitate*** is right there anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers not splitting any hairs at all. And not going for deeper roots, but indeed the exact opposite. I don't care what the deeper root of the French word *hospitable* is in French. Or what the deeper root of the German word *zeitgeist* is in German. Or what the deeper root of the Russian word *perestroyka* is in Russian. I am looking at the English roots of the English words *hospitable, zeitgeist, perestroyka*. And the English roots of these English words are *hospitable, zeitgeist, perestroyka*, respectively. Not *hospice*, not *tide* and *ghost*, and not *stroy*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Well, I'm aware that OED's first cite for ***hospitate*** is several centuries later than their first cite for ***hospitable***, so it makes no sense to claim that the longer word actually "came" from the shorter one. But the connection between ***hospice*** and ***hospitable*** seems clear enough to me, and I have the impression OP here wasn't originally inclined to accept any meaningful link between the two words - so essentially, he was wrong and the lecturer was right. Whatever - we both know perfectly well that you know more about such things than me! :)

Answer (score 1):

From the morphological point of view, the noun 'hospitability' is the derivative of 'hospitable' formed by affixation.
The noun 'hospitable' is a root word because it was  borrowed as a  'ready-made' adjective from French.
See Etymology Online Dictionary:
hospitable (adj.)

"kind and cordial to strangers or guests," 1560s, from Middle French hospitable, which is formed as if from a Medieval Latin hospitabilis, from the stem of Latin hospitari"be a guest," from hospes (genitive hospitis) "guest" (see host (n.1)). The Latin adjective was hospitalis, but this became a noun in Old French and entered English as hospital. Related: Hospitably.

Answer (score 0):

The earliest recorded root is the Latin word *hospit-* (nominative *hospes*) which means "guest". *Hospice*, *hospital* and *hostel* are all derived from it by different routes.

It in turn goes back to the Indo-European **gʰóstis* "stranger, guest, enemy", which also underlies both *hostile* and *guest*. See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hospes)